# How am i able to search for inputs in a file and print them in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Springfork Amateur Golf Club has a tournament every weekend. The club president has asked you to write four programs:

A. A program that will read each player's name and golf score as keyboard input, the save these records in a file named golf.txt.(Each record will have a field for the player's name and a field for the player's score)

B. A program that reads the records from the golf.txt file and displays them.

C. A program that searches for a particular record when player's name is given.

D. A program that modifies score of a player.

I've got the first 2 parts down but struggling to complete part C and D

This is what I have so far

```
def main():
    move_on = 'y'
    golfScoreFile = open('golfRecords.txt', 'a')
    while move_on == 'y' or move_on == 'Y':
        pName = input("Enter the player's name: ")
        pScore = int(input("Enter the player's score: "))
        golfScoreFile.write(pName + "\n")
        golfScoreFile.write(str(pScore) + "\n")
        move_on = input("Would you like to continue? [y]: ")
    displayRecords = input("Would you like to display all the records from golfRecords.txt? [y]: ")
    golfScoreFile.close()
    if (displayRecords == 'y' or displayRecords == 'Y'):
        displayRecs()
    else:
        searchRecs()


def displayRecs():
    golfScoreFile = open('golfRecords.txt', 'r')
    lineCount = 1
    for line in golfScoreFile:
        golfRecLine = lineCount % 2
        if (golfRecLine == 0):
            print("The score of this person is: ", line)
        if (golfRecLine == 1):
            print("The name of this person is: ", line)
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
    golfScoreFile.close()


def searchRecs():
    search = input("Enter players name to search: ")

def modscore():



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Please paste your saved file code:')
    file_load_code = input('')
    file = open('logs.txt', 'r')
    logs = file.read()
    if file_load_code in logs:
      print('Finding file...')
      time.sleep(0.2)
      print('Found!')
      print('Press enter to fully load the file:')
      ENTER = input('')
      file.close()
      file = open('file_context.txt', 'r')
      for x in file:
        if file_load_code in x:
          print(x)
```

Try that!

Comment: I am looking for something a bit different. I need it to ask for an input of a player name then find that players name and score located in the file of the main function. Then print the score and name of player.

Comment: @mas284 i just edited it, tell me if that worked!

Comment: IT kind of worked. It was able to find the name but i also need it to present the score associated with the name

Comment: Make sure to rewrite the users score next to the name to read just that line

Comment: I unfortunately cannot do that because it needs the score displayed on a separate line. can i have it print this score line as well as the name line?

Comment: I am trying to print the next line but it continues to give me "TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator"

Comment: You can do something like this:
    Thing = str(player, score)
    Print(Thing)

Comment: But i need the function to find the players score as well.

Comment: Hmmmm…  Sorry, I dont think i can help.  That’s how i normally do it, good luck!